# Error compiling xmonad.hs

Tags: xmonad, tiling-wm, haskell

I was trying to make different workspace have different layout, I found this module -  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Layout-PerWorkspace.html

I imported `XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace` in my `xmonad.hs` and added these lines -

```
onWorkspace ["2"] noBorders monocle $  -- layout l1 will be used on workspace "2".
onWorkspace ["9"] smartBorders Full $  -- layout l2 will be used on workspace "6".
```

in `myLayoutHook`

```
-- The layout hook
myLayoutHook = avoidStruts $ mouseResize $ windowArrange $ T.toggleLayouts floats $
               mkToggle (NBFULL ?? NOBORDERS ?? EOT) myDefaultLayout

               onWorkspace ["2"] noBorders monocle $  -- layout l1 will be used on workspace "2".
               onWorkspace ["9"] smartBorders Full $  -- layout l2 will be used on workspace "6".

             where
               -- I've commented out the layouts I don't use.
               myDefaultLayout =     tall
                                 ||| noBorders monocle
                                 ||| floats
                                 ||| grid
                                 ||| smartBorders Full
```

but I'm getting an error while recompiling `xmonad`

```
> xmonad --recompile                                                                                                                         
XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/apoorv/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/apoorv/.xmonad/xmonad.hs
xmonad.hs:620:14: error: parse error on input ‘where’
    |
620 |              where
    |              ^^^^^
Please check the file for errors.
Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
```

Comment: Probably an indentation issue.

Comment: I have checked it already, I don't see any indentation problem. However if I comment out the 2 lines I added `onWorkspace`, it compiles fine. My full config (if needed) - https://gitlab.com/apoorv569/dotfiles/-/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$`...

The general format is:

```
abc
$ xyz123 
$ xyz456
```

While you seem to have:

```
abc
xyz123 $
xyz456 $
```

Comment: The documentation had this example which I copied, 
`layoutHook = modWorkspace "baz" m1 $  -- apply layout modifier m1 to all layouts on workspace "baz"
             onWorkspace "foo" l1 $  -- layout l1 will be used on workspace "foo".
             onWorkspaces ["bar","6"] l2 $  -- layout l2 will be used on workspaces "bar" and "6".
             l3                      -- layout l3 will be used on all other workspaces.`

Comment: Exactly? After `$` you need some parameter. Which in their case ends with `l3`, while in you end with `$`. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521246/what-does-mean-do-in-haskell/19521376

Comment: The documentation has
`onWorkspace "foo" l1 $`
and I did
`onWorkspace ["2"] noBorders monocle $`
where `l1` or `l3` are layouts.
what am I getting wrong here?